# How to insert child into QTreeWidget hierarchy?

Tags: c++, qt, hierarchy, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

Consider I have QTreeWidget with following items hierarchy:

```
top_item
  |--child
```

Every item has assigned with `setItemWidget()` widget.
I need to insert another child between my first two elements like this :

```
top_item
  |--another_child
     |--child
```

I trying to do that with following code:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* top_item = new QTreeWidgetItem;
ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(top_item);
QTreeWidgetItem* child_item = new QTreeWidgetItem;
top_item->addChild(child_item);

ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(top_item, 0, new QPushButton);
ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(child_item, 0, new QPushButton);

// ---- let's insert another child ----
auto last_children = top_item->takeChildren();

QTreeWidgetItem* another_child_item = new QTreeWidgetItem;
top_item->insertChild(0, another_child_item);
ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(another_child_item, 0, new QPushButton);

another_child_item->addChildren(last_children);
```

It works fine except one moment — it lost assigned widgets.
I've tried to take and save the widgets before taking children with

```
QWidget* widget_from_child_item = ui->treeWidget->itemWidget(child_item, 0);
ui->treeWidget->removeItemWidget(child_item, 0);
```

but after calling `takeChildren()` all assigned widgets have been deleted and app is crashing after reassigning the widgets with `setItemWidget()`.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the same thing:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *child = ui->treeWidget->currentItem();
QTreeWidgetItem *parent = child->parent();

if(parent)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *another_child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    another_child->setText(0,"another_child");
    parent->addChild(another_child);
    another_child->addChild(parent->takeChild(parent->indexOfChild(child)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recognized by Qt documentation that `QWidget` isn't actually linked to `QTreeWidgetItem`: both methods `QTreeWidget::setItemWidget` and `QTreeWidget::itemWidget` have a comment

> Note: The tree takes ownership of the widget.

In my case (insert child between others parent and child) I've implemented a next solution:

1. Implement `get_copy()` method for my widget
2. Before taking item from `QTreeWidget` copying a linked widgets
3. After inserting new item and moving old item, assign copied widgets to appropriate `QTreeWidgetItem`

Here a small example:

```
void insert_tree_item(i_tree_item* new_widget_item)
{
  QTreeWidgetItem* current_item = _tree_widget->currentItem();

  if(current_item->childCount())
  {
    QList<QWidget*> widgets;
    widgets.push_front(dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(new_widget_item));
    QTreeWidgetItem* ptr = current_item->child(0);
    while(ptr != nullptr)
    {
        QWidget* widget = _tree_widget->itemWidget(ptr, 0);
        widgets.push_back(dynamic_cast<i_tree_item*>(widget)->get_copy());
        auto prev_ptr = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->child(0);
        if(ptr == nullptr)
        {
            prev_ptr->addChild(new QTreeWidgetItem);
        }
    }
    ptr = current_item->child(0);
    while(widgets.count() != 0)
    {
        _tree_widget->setItemWidget(ptr, 0, widgets.takeFirst());
        ptr = ptr->child(0);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    QTreeWidgetItem* new_item = new QTreeWidgetItem;
    current_item->addChild(new_item);
    _tree_widget->setItemWidget(new_item, 0, dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(new_widget_item));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void insertAParent() {
   if (tree->selectedItems().count() != 1)
      return;

   QTreeWidgetItem *item = tree->selectedItems().front();
   QTreeWidgetItem *oldParent = item->parent();
   if (oldParent) {
       int index = oldParent->indexOfChild(item);
       item = oldParent->takeChild(index);
       QTreeWidgetItem *newParent = new QTreeWidgetItem;
       newParent->setText(0, tr("Something"));
       oldParent->insertChild(index, newParent);
       newParent->insertChild(0, item);
   }
}
```

Comment: problem is not how to insert a child into existent hierarchy, problem is how to save children's widgets.

Comment: try my solution. If I understand correctly you have messed up usage of `removeItemWidget` and `takeChildren`. Also try to improve question.

Comment: Yes, it is a first thing that I had done: try your solution. Ok, thanks for advice, will try soon.